# wired acting operators in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

this is my query:

```
db.Users.Where(u =>
  ( u.Mobile.Contains(SearchStr)
   || u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(SearchStr.ToLower())
   || u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(SearchStr.ToLower())
   || (u.Email.Contains(SearchStr)
  )
  && (u.Type == SearchType || SearchType == 0)
  && (Confirmed == null || Confirmed == u.IsVerified)
  && (Banned == null || Banned == u.IsDeleted)
 )
```

This list all the users ignoring the `Confirmed`,`Banned` and `SearchType`. the result are the same whether these values are `null`, `true` or `false`

Comment: I think something is getting messed up in your condition which you can identiofy easily by debuggin but problem is they way you have to written this condition makes it difficult to debug....Move the whole logic in method something like IsConditionPassed and have all this check inside that method which will help you to debug also

Comment: Have you looked at what SQL is being produced for the query?

Comment: @JonHanna how do I do that?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani The easiest way is if let say `var query = ...`, then `var sql = query.ToString();`

Comment: `db.Database.Log` will also take an `Action<string>` that it will call with log output including the queries executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the open parentheses here

```
(u.Email.Contains(SearchStr)
```

which basically makes the condition like `A OR B OR C AND D AND E AND F`. I don't know (and I don't even want to know) how such logical expression is evaluated, and most probably the result is not what you expect.

Try this instead

```
var query = db.Users.Where(u =>
    (u.Mobile.Contains(SearchStr)
       || u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(SearchStr.ToLower())
       || u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(SearchStr.ToLower())
       || u.Email.Contains(SearchStr)
    )
    && (u.Type == SearchType || SearchType == 0)
    && (Confirmed == null || Confirmed == u.IsVerified)
    && (Banned == null || Banned == u.IsDeleted)
);
```

Comment: isn't it exactly same query as mine?

Comment: Same with one `(` removed :)

Answer (score 0):

`If SearchType == 0 or Confirmed == null or Banned == null` at any point, it will return everything. This is likely the case

Remove those conditions and you should be good

Comment: imagine that `Confirmed=true` then no matter what is the value of `Banned` why should it return the result that its `Confirmed` value is `false`?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of comment then answer but wanted to show code which might help OP to debug

```
  db.Users.Where(u =>ISPassed(u));

    private bool IsPassed(User u)
    {
// put a debugger here
     return ( u.Mobile.Contains(SearchStr)
       || u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(SearchStr.ToLower())
       || u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(SearchStr.ToLower())
       || (u.Email.Contains(SearchStr)
      )
      && (u.Type == SearchType || SearchType == 0)
      && (Confirmed == null || Confirmed == u.IsVerified)
      && (Banned == null || Banned == u.IsDeleted));
    }
```

Comment: This is not Linq To Objects, hence you cannot debug it this way. You cannot even run it because custom functions like this are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the generated sql as [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) said.
Adding another pair of parentheses solved the problem, but still I'm not getting the logic, that why didn't work before and why is working now

```
db.Users.Where(
                        u =>
                        ((  u.Mobile.Contains(SearchStr) //added the parantheses in here
                        || u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(SearchStr.ToLower())
                        || u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(SearchStr.ToLower())
                        || (u.Email.Contains(SearchStr)
                        )) //and here
                        && (u.Type == SearchType || SearchType == 0)
                        && (Confirmed == null || Confirmed == u.IsVerified)
                        && (Banned == null || Banned == u.IsDeleted)

                        ))
```